# Ampscript, IF statement doesn't work

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript

I have condition if "color" is red or purple and "year" greater than "number", it would show google link, otherwise if not within those categories it would show facebook link.

```ampscript
    SET @Number = 2023
    SET @Year = 2022
    SET @Color = [Color]
            
    if (IndexOf(@Color,'red') > 0 or IndexOf(@Color,'purple') > 0) and @Year > @Number then
    SET @Link = "https://google.com/"
    
    else
           
    SET @Link = "https://www.facebook.com/"
          
    endif
```

In my DE, I have "red B", so depend on the code instead of showing google.com or Facebook.com, it shows default link: https://user-content.s10.sfmc-content.com/

What did I do wrong? why it's showing https://user-content.s10.sfmc-content.com/ ? eventhough I have %%=RedirectTo(@Link)=%%

Answer (score 0):

You have multiple issues in the code. All the URLs need to start with 'https://' in order to work properly. Hence you will need to update your `@link` variables.

You don't show your link tag, buy you need to use the [RedirectTo](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/marketing/marketing-cloud/guide/redirectto.html?q=redirect%20to) function in your href tag. This function is required when using the  HTML hyperlink tag in emails when the hypertext reference (href) attribute is either an attribute or a variable and the hyperlink is a tracked email link.

Additionally, you must also update the IndexOf functions, as you are not calling the variables correctly. Instead of using: `IndexOf(Color,'red')`, you must do `IndexOf(@Color,'red')`

Comment: Thanks for your comment, for the url I just forgot to add https on the sample code, but it's there on my real code. For the hyperlink tag also is there, but not shown in the sample code. For IndexOf, I just made an edit, adding @ on the variable, but still not working

Comment: @Uss - please provide more context and share your actual code, as seeing parts of it with typos, does not give us any good basis for helping you...